# Separating a Tiff image stack in python

Tags: python, image-processing, tiff

I'm currently writing code for a photonics lab in Boston and  recently encountered an issue using tiff images. Basically, the company's lab returns a Tiff image with a stack of 4 images under a single file name and I'm unsure how to get python to read the stacked images one at a time.

For the code I use (pasted below) I've been saving each image manually under different names and read them in as a list of names. Is there a python library or command I've missed that will recognize the stack without me needing to do this?

```
def Image_Processing(img_list, wave_list):
counter = 0
r_final = []

#for loop where I read in an image at a time from the img_list
for i in img_list:

#this is just image processing crap
    Im = plt.imread(i)
    #print(Im.shape,Im[0,0])
    Dim_List = []
    Bright_List = []
    Imarray = np.array(Im)
    for line in Imarray:
        for pixel in line:
            if pixel <= 20000:
                Dim_List.append(pixel)
            if pixel > 20000:
                Bright_List.append(pixel)
    d = np.mean(Dim_List)
    b = np.mean(Bright_List)
    r_final.append((d/b)*wave_list[counter])
    counter += 1
print(r_final)
Image_Processing(['fourColor-0001.tif', 'fourColor-0002.tif', 'fourColor-0003.tif', 'fourColor-0004.tif'], [.453,.523,.597,.636])
```

Comment: do yu have an example tiff file you can post somewhere? Python has tens of third party modules able to deal with image files. From those, that which can deal with tiff files will normally use the open-source libtiff - but the only way to know if one of the Python libraries can properly deal with image stack is by trying

Comment: Meanwhile, try to install Python-pillow - it is proably the most used Python Image package around. I am not sure it can deal with multiple images in a tiff (for GIFs it does so poorly)

Comment: GDAL and the GDAL python bindings will read multi-band tiff files.